# Python: For loop comparing current with previous iteration

Tags: python, list, for-loop, compare, iteration

I have a for loop that I got here, that uses bubblesort to sort a list of strings, and in every iteration the list is changed a bit... is there a way to compare the product of the previous iteration with the current one?

As it stands it simply prints the product of each iteration. I would need a way to call back the previous product, to latter compare it with the product of the last iteration.

```
lst = ["bubble", "bath", "with", "bacon"]

def bubble(lst):
    unsorted = True
    while unsorted:
        unsorted = False             
        for j in range(len(lst) - 1):
            if lst[j] > lst[j + 1]:
                hold = lst[j + 1]
                lst[j + 1] = lst[j]
                lst[j] = hold
                print(lst)
                unsorted = True
```

Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: You can easily save a copy of the former list just by adding `backup=lst[:]` before the for loop, but what do you mean by "compare"? simple comparison of equality?

Comment: Indeed a simple comparison of equality, and afterwards, if they are not the same, manipulating with them, but I got that covered. Thank you :)

Comment: Python doesn't require a temporary variable to swap two items: `lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1], lst[j]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a copy of the list using a `[:]` after each iteration. While this code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
```

...simply stores a reference to the same list in `b`, this code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[:]
```

...creates a full copy of `a` and stores it in `b`. Thus, any subsequent changes to `a` will not affect `b`.